# What is -cos(t) equivalent to in terms of cos(t)

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know if,

> $-\cos(t) = \cos(t+180)$

or

> $-\cos(t) = \cos(t-180)$

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: See [*Shift by area*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity)

Comment: Both. A 180 degree shift in a sinusoidal function is indistinguishable from a phase reversal.

Comment: Use the degree symbol: "^\circ".  If you don't use it, you are using radians.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, both are true: $$-\cos (t) = \cos (t \pm 180^\circ)\quad\text{ or in radians, }\;\;-\cos(t) = (t \pm \pi)$$

Note that $$t + 180^\circ - (t - 180^\circ) = 360^\circ$$
See this link for similar [trigonometric "shifts"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity)

In the same Wikipedia article, you'll find a handy diagram with ordered pairs $(\cos x, \sin x)$ for angle x measured in *radians*, as they appear cycle the unit circle:

[image]

Comment: You guys type fast! +1

Comment: @Amzoti: Yes, they are toooo fast. and this is why I cannot make my approach as soon as possible. Nice to see you here. +1 for being fast.

Comment: @BabakS.: Hello my friend - good to see you again!

Answer (score 4):

Both answers are correct. Note that $t+180^\circ$ and $t-180^\circ$ differ by $360^\circ$, so they have the same cosine (and sine).

Let's verify that $\cos(t+180^\circ)=-\cos t$. If you rotate a point $(x,y)$ around the origin  through $180^\circ$, both the $x$ and $y$-coordinate of the point change sign. It follows that $\cos(t+180^\circ)=-\cos t$ and $\sin(t+180^\circ)=-\sin t$.

Answer (score 0):

As a separate verification, you can use the "angle-addition" formula for cosine:

$$\cos (t \pm 180^{\circ})  = \cos t \cdot \cos (\pm 180^{\circ}) \mp \sin t \cdot \sin (\pm 180^{\circ})$$

$$= (\cos t) \cdot [-1] \mp (\sin t) \cdot 0  = -\cos t .$$

You can reconstruct a lot of trig identities for complementary angles, supplementary angles, etc. with the angle-addition rules for sine, cosine, and tangent.